# Unable to find R in ubuntu while r-base is correctly installed

Tags: apt, package-management, r

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS , I decided to update my version of R to 4.3. After encountering several difficulties, I completely removed R (including removing all system files related to R, such as /usr/lib/R). However, even after reinstalling R, I was unable to get the program to work. All the programs that are using R like Rstudio are not working and it looks like R is not found by Ubuntu.

```
command not found: R
```

But if I try to reinstall R, it indicates that everything is properly installed.

```
> ~ ❯❯❯ sudo apt install -y r-base r-base-core r-recommended r-base-dev  ✘ 127  
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
r-base-core is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
r-base-dev is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
r-base is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
r-recommended is already the newest version (4.3.0-1.2204.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

I have tried multiple times to uninstall and reinstall, but I haven't found any solution. Does someone know how to make it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I completely removed R (including removing all system files related to
> R, such as /usr/lib/R).

Tells me that you manually deleted some R related files and considered that as an uninstall of R ... Regardless of what you did, APT will still consider R as installed as it will not look around to see that you have deleted some files but it will rather check its database of installed packages which will tell it that R is installed and therefore it will report as such when you try to install it.

APT uninstalls packaged with `apt remove <package>` or `apt purge <package>` and only then it will consider a package not-installed.

To fix that, you'll need to reinstall with APT's `--reinstall` flag like so:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall r-base r-base-core r-recommended r-base-dev
```

That will tell APT to perform an actual install regardless if those packages are reported as installed or not in its database.